# Can anyone solve this indifference curve question?

Tags: microeconomics

*Draw the indifference curves for a preference relation which is neither monotonous
or strictly convex, yet convex.*

My solution was to draw a circle but I'm pretty sure that is wrong.

Comment: That might work on "not monotonous" depending on what that means (related to satiation?),  but a circle might be seen a strictly convex, so some adjustment might be needed, such as a rectangle

Answer (score 3):

Consider the utility function $u(x, y)= -|x-5|-|y-5|$.

Indifference map for $u$ is as follows :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

How do you define monotonicity? The definition of monotonicity in economics is usually:

$x\geq y$ implies that $U(x)\geq U(y)$.

Then a solution could be:

$U(x_1,x_2)=x_1-x_2$

[image]

However, if you use the mathematical definition of monotonic function, then here is one of the solutions:

[image].

You need to add the coordinates by yourself.